# How to change AES cipher to RSA

Tags: authentication, cryptography

I have a .net application that is working for a while. With SSL3.0 being phased out, our webserver was upgraded to a different platform that supports multiples ciphers but not the one I am using. My new app is using AES128. Is there a way to convert or use RSA as opposed to AES? Or how can I inject different cipher during two way handshake/authentication? I am currently using .net 4.0 framework.

Comment: TLS uses RSA and AES together for different purposes. The two are not interchangeable. Please clarify your question. What do you mean "how to change"? Like what code would you write to configure a TLS client connection with a certain cipher suite enabled? Or what?

Answer (score 2):

RSA is not a substitute for AES.

AES is a symmetric cipher that can quickly encrypt and decrypt large messages.

RSA is an asymmetric cypher that requires large, expensive-to-generate keys, and large amounts of computations for encrypting and decrypting. In practice, RSA is only used to encrypt a symmetric key that is itself used to encrypt the rest of the message.

An SSL/TLS cryptographic suite specifies a way to exchange keys (RSA is one) and a symmetric cipher (AES128 is one). They can be used in complement of each other or with other primitives, but one cannot replace the other. An example of a choice of cryptographic suite may look like RSA_AES_256_SHA. In this one RSA and AES256 are used together.

Comment: I guess, I used the wrong terminologies. What is happening is that during httpwebrequest, I compared my old application uses TriplesDES cipher and my new uses AES128, the old app was coded in java and the new was coded in  c#. The old worked flawlessly, the new one failed during handshake.  So I am guessing this is a cipher issue which the client and server can't agree on which prompted me play around with the cipher but to no avail.

Comment: @Clara 3DES **is** a symmetric cipher of the same type as AES. It is exactly the sort of symmetric cipher that would be supported in old software and would have been removed because now considered insufficiently secure in recent software.